# Search images in 'a' links with BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get all `<a href=''>` that contains an image (jpg,png,jpeg)

First I found that I can download links with this Beautifulsoup code

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print "Found the URL:", a['href']
```

But I get all  strings I only want to get images .

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
url = requests.get("https://8ch.net/a/res/869528.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text,"html.parser")
print soup
for a in soup.find_all(re.compile('([-\w]+\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png))') ):#'a', href=True):
    print "Found the URL:", a #['href']
```

after that I found that I can use a regex expression that find all link that contains a link.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just finished what you want to do. I will describe the usage of code with note.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
url = requests.get("https://8ch.net/a/res/869528.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text,"html.parser")
for a in soup.find_all("a" , href=True):
    if re.findall(r".+(?=jpg|png|jpeg)",a['href']): 
    # find out if the url contain jpg or png or jpeg , if not return a empty list. empty list is False
        print(a['href'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think regex is little overkill here. Just need the check the value after the rightmost dot.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = requests.get("https://8ch.net/a/res/869528.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if a["href"][a["href"].rfind(".")+1:] in ["jpeg", "png", "jpg"]:
        print(a["href"])
```